# How can I rename a file on unix using characters in filename?

Tags: solaris, rename

I have a bunch of files in a unix directory that look like the following:

```
filename_1234567.txt
```

I need to rename them by copying the last three characters of each filename to the front of the filename like this:

```
567_filename_1234567.txt
```

NOTE: The extension as well as the filename are variable.

I'm running this on a Solaris box.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv
zmv -n '*(???).*' '$1_$f'
```

Remove `-n` when happy.

Comment: This was flagged as low quality. Go figure.

Comment: @don_crissti `zsh` is way too terse for its own good

Comment: It would be a better answer if it explained how it works.  I can infer that the pattern matched by `(???)` is referenced by `$1`, and `$f` is the original filename, and that `-n` is a dry-run switch, but others mightn't be able to.

Comment: @DopeGhoti, in my experience those who want to learn would jump on the opportunity of reading the manual to find out what that does and what more can be one. Those who don't would not even read the few words that would be needed to paraphrase that code. Yes, a few words of explanation would be nice, but we get quite a few of those questions per week and one gets bored after a while. Anybody's welcome to edit the answer to add those words.

Answer (score 2):

So you wish to prepend the last three characters of the file's basename, followed by an underscore, to the front of the filename?

```
#!/bin/bash
EXT=.txt
for file in *${EXT}; do # presuming all the filenames have no spaces 
   base=${file%${EXT}}
   prefix=${base:(-3)}
   newname=${prefix}_${base}${EXT}
   mv ${file} ${newname}
done
```

---

This will not work in the Korn shell, as the tricks it uses are `bash`-specific:

```
ksh[3]: prefix=${base:(-3)}: bad substitution
```

---

Comment: This solution relies on `bash` string substitution, so the script can't use e. g. the Korn shell.

Comment: two errors in your script: 1) `base=${file%${EXT}/}` should be `base=${file%${EXT}}` (no trailing /). 2) `prefix= ${base:(-3)}` should be `prefix=${base:(-3)}` (no space after =).

Comment: Ways on ksh: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24553476/2072269

Comment: It will work on ksh93, not ksh88. bash copied that syntax from ksh. With ksh88 or any POSIX shell `prefix=${base#"${base%???}"}`

Answer (score 1):

I like to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in filename_*.txt; do echo "$i"; done |
sed "s/filename_\([0-9]*\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)\.txt/mv -i 'filename_\1\2.txt' '\2_filename_\1\2.txt'/g"
```

This prints the list of `mv` commands to accomplish the task.  If it prints the correct commands, then just append `| sh` at the end of the sed command to cause the shell to execute them.

This script uses the `sed` subsitute command `s` and the back reference feature to use parts of the matched regular expression in the replacement string.

```
s/regex/replacement/
```

The parts of the regular expression pattern between `\(` and `\)` can be referenced in the replacement string by `\N` where in is a number.

Comment: You don't need to do a `for i in file*; do echo "$i"`; you can just `for i in file*`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti I don't think so. Please explain.

Comment: Oh.  OH, I misread your piping.  I thought you were taking each file's name, echoing it, and iterating over _that_, not piping the entire list to sed.  I'd still be inclined to just use `ls -1 filename_*.txt | sed [...]` rather than use a `for` loop though.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Yes, either way should work, but the `for` loop version is safer.   The `-1` option is redundant, `ls` prints one filename to a line when output to a pipe. The `ls` method is much more clear, which also counts.  If I was doing this in my own system where I know what's going on, I would use `ls`.

Answer (score 1):

You're on Solaris so you'll have `perl`. You might even have `rename` (or possibly `prename`):

```
rename -n 's/^(.*)(.{3})(\.[^.]*)$/$2_$1$2$3/' *.*
```

Remove `-n` or change it to `-v` when you're ready to roll.

Comment: Rename not available on box.

Answer (score 1):

Pure `awk` solution: basic idea is to extract last 3 chars of the basename, that means a substring form `length - 6` (6 because need to account for the `.txt` extension) to `length - 3`. Here I merely extract that substring into VAR first, then create the command complete with `mv` and two filenames to be ran; finally I ask `system` function to run the command.

Code:

```
awk 'BEGIN{
           VAR=sprintf("%s",substr(ARGV[1],length(ARGV[1])-6,3)); 
           CMD=("mv "ARGV[1]" "VAR"_"ARGV[1]); 
           print CMD; 
           system(CMD); 
           close(CMD)
          }' filename_1234567.txt
```

Demo:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{VAR=sprintf("%s",substr(ARGV[1],length(ARGV[1])-6,3)); CMD=("mv "ARGV[1]" "VAR"_"ARGV[1]); print CMD; system(CMD); close(CMD)}' filename_1234567.txt 
mv filename_1234567.txt 567_filename_1234567.txt
$ ls filename_1234567.txt
ls: cannot access filename_1234567.txt: No such file or directory
$ ls 567_filename_1234567.txt
567_filename_1234567.txt
$
```